# CKAN 2.2.1 - create organisation - logic.action

Tags: ckan

I am using CKAN 2.2.1.
The extension I am working on needs to:

- find the organisation id
  or
- create new organisation if name does not mach during the creation of the dataset.

So far I am using `logic.action.get.organization_show` and `logic.action.create.organization_create` but I am not convinced to that method.

What is the right way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly valid. Here are a couple of examples of this approach in other extensions:

- https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-tsbsatellites/blob/master/ckanext/tsbsatellites/plugin.py#L206:L229
- https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/master/ckanext/harvest/harvesters/ckanharvester.py#L319:L336

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!